# WCF B2B Scenario - Client Certificate Requirements

Tags: wcf, ssl

WCF Service hosted under the company SSL certificate is to use Peer authentication of client's X509 certificate for authentication.

What are the recommended requirements for the client company's certificate?

Do they require to purchase a CA root and use this to issue a certificate or would a self-signed be sufficient?

How best for the client to send their certificate for installation in the Trusted People store of the server?